# I need to Edit and update the repeater values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I have a repeater that has five column (ITEM,ITEM DESCRIPTION,PRICE ,QUANTITY AND TOTAL).I am binding the values to repeater from database table for the columns ITEM,ITEM DESCRIPTION AND QUANTITY and Two columns ( PRICE AND TOTAL) are felt blank because this has to be filled by the user.How can i achieve this(it may have many rows) ?

This my repeater code:

```
<div id="RPT">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptrAtchmnt_ItemCommand"
                                            OnItemDataBound="RptrAtchmnt_ItemDatabound">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan=".5">
                                                        S.NO
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        ITEM
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th colspan="4">
                                                        ITEM DESCRIPTION
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        PRICE
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        QUANTITY
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        TOTAL
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        DELETE
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSINo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sino")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblITEM" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITEM")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td colspan="4">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEXTENSION" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DES")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPRICE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRI")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QTY")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTOTAL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TOT")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td id="RptrAtchRemve" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:Button ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btn red" CommandName="Remove"
                                                            CausesValidation="false" DataKeyNames="sino" Text="Remove" Width="90px" Height="37px"
                                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("sino")%>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                        <tr id="FileUploadRow" runat="server">
                                            <td colspan="1">
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="1">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_item" placeholder="ENTER ITEM " runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="4">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_itemdes" placeholder="ENTER ITEM DESCRIPTION  " runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="1">
                                                <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_PRI"
                                                    FilterType="Numbers">
                                                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PRI" placeholder="ENTER ITEM PRICE" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="1">
                                                <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_qty"
                                                    FilterType="Numbers">
                                                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_qty" placeholder="ENTER ITEM QUANTITY" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="1">
                                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Add" CssClass="btn green" OnClientClick="btnUpload"
                                                    runat="server" Width="90px" Height="37px" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

This C# code :

```
 #region "REPEATER TO TEMP TABLE"
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string ITEM = txt_item.Text;
    string ITEM_DES = txt_itemdes.Text;
    string ITEM_QTY = txt_qty.Text;
    string ITEM_PRICE = txt_PRI.Text;
    int ITEM_TOTAL = Convert.ToInt32(txt_PRI.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txt_qty.Text);
    BindRptr(ITEM_QTY, ITEM, ITEM_DES, ITEM_PRICE, ITEM_TOTAL);
    txt_item.Text = "";
    txt_itemdes.Text = "";
    txt_qty.Text = "";
    txt_PRI.Text = "";

}
#endregion


#region LoadItem
public void LoaditmRptr(string QUOT_ID)
{
    using (logsystemDataContext db_rept = new logsystemDataContext())
    {
        var _item = (from itm in db_rept.quotation_items
                     where itm.quotation_id.Equals(QUOT_ID)
                     select new
                     {
                         itm.item,
                         itm.item_des,
                         itm.qty,
                         itm.price,
                         itm.total_price,
                     }).ToList();

        if (_item.Count != 0)
        {

            int count;
            TempTable = DataColumn();
            foreach (var itm in _item)
            {
                count = TempTable.Rows.Count + 1;
                DataRow dr = TempTable.NewRow();
                dr["sino"] = count;
                dr["QTY"] = itm.qty;
                dr["ITEM"] = itm.item;
                dr["DES"] = itm.item_des;
                dr["PRI"] = itm.price;
                dr["TOT"] = itm.total_price;
                TempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = TempTable;
            }
            Repeater1.DataSource = TempTable;
            Repeater1.DataBind();

        }
        else
            LoadEmptyReptrAttachment();
    }
}
#endregion


public DataTable DataColumn()
{
    TempTable.Clear();
    TempTable.Columns.Add("sino");
    TempTable.Columns.Add("QTY");
    TempTable.Columns.Add("ITEM");
    TempTable.Columns.Add("DES");
    TempTable.Columns.Add("PRI");
    TempTable.Columns.Add("TOT");
    TempTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { TempTable.Columns["sino"] };
    return TempTable;
}
#endregion
```

PLEASE HELP IT NEED TO DONE IMMM....

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, both price and total are labels, I suppose at least on them them will be changed to a textbox later and that you want to do retrieve the value and do the calculation on the server side. 
Upon pushback, loop through the items of the repeater. Be aware that not only content items but also the header and footer items are enumerated, so you might want to check for the type of the item. For the items on question, you can use FindControl along with the control id to access a specific control in the item. This way, you can retrieve or change values in the item. You also apply this technique later when storing data into the database.
There are plenty of examples ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281559/asp-net-repeater-loop-through-items-in-the-item-template), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855228/getting-dropdownlist-values-in-a-repeater?rq=1)) for this on the web, so I won't provide a code sample.